# question on rooting

Tags: server

Rooting a server is done through uploading a shell on a target website and running a root exploit to gain root privileges on a server thus gaining access to sites that are hosted on that shared server.
My question is, what is preventing a person from just buying a site on a shared server and upload a shell himself and root the server to gain access to their sites hosted on it (the administrator of a site himself on a server)?
Also, why is it not possible to root servers like the ones available on free hosting at 000webhost (because of the large number of disabled php functions?).

Answer (score 7):

There are many other methods (of course) to attack web servers, but lets limit ourselves to the method you're interested in - getting some file onto the server, and making the server execute it. The major access control that prevents total destruction of web servers is **file permissions**, and an important secondary control is **media-type** instructions on the web server. I'm explaining how these work on Linux/Unix, which accounts for the [majority of web servers in use today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems#Servers).

Broadly speaking, your web directory where the files that constitute your website are (usually something like /var/www for simple installations) will have [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) that control which users are able to read, write, and execute files.

A properly configured system will have permissions that permit only the operations that are required, and nothing further. That means that a malicious user would not be able to upload his malicious payload, because he would not have write access.

Perhaps the web server admin made a mistake with file permissions? The second layer of security is [**media-type** instructions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html). So even after uploading a PHP pseudo-shell like "[phpshell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/)", the web server may have been told [not to execute any PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess). (e.g. something like "AddType text/plain php").

For shared hosting, the most common security measure is indeed by disabling PHP (by whatever method). Also, many hosting providers provide a single Virtual Machine for each customer, so even if you manage to root the VM somehow, you can't break into any other VMs, or the VM host.